# Comparing 2 items at different dates

Tags: netezza

I have a Netezza database which gets a daily feed of account information.

I’m trying to write a query which will only return accounts when they experience a price change and advise what the price change was. I.E. in the example below it would return account 100 having a price change of +10 on 2020-02-02.

```
Date                  Account             Price
2020-02-01       100                    200
2020-02-01       101                    200
2020-02-01       102                    200
2020-02-02       100                    210
2020-02-02       101                    200
2020-02-02       102                    200
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a Netezza device, but according to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netezza),

> Netezza software was based on PostgreSQL 7.2,[9] but did not maintain
>   compatibility.

so, I'll use the PostgreSQL option for the fiddle which you can find [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3ababbf37f19486ac0079ffcf1274be5). According to the documentation, Netezza has [Window/Analytic functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_window_analytic_funcs.html).

What I did to answer your question was:

Create a `share` table:

```
CREATE TABLE share 
(
  t_date  DATE NOT NULL, -- BAD IDEA to use SQL keywords for fieldnames! 
  account INTEGER NOT NULL,
  price   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO share 
VALUES
('2020-02-01',       100,                    200),
('2020-02-01',       101,                    200),
('2020-02-01',       102,                    200),
('2020-02-02',       100,                    210),
('2020-02-02',       101,                    200),
('2020-02-02',       102,                    200);
```

Then I ran the following query (using Window - or Analytic - functions):

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rn,
  t_date AS d, account AS a, 
  LAG(price) OVER () AS la, price, LEAD(price) OVER() AS le
FROM share;
```

Result:

```
rn  d   a   la  price   le
1   2020-02-01  100     200 200
2   2020-02-01  101 200 200 200
3   2020-02-01  102 200 200 210
4   2020-02-02  100 200 210 200
5   2020-02-02  101 210 200 200
6   2020-02-02  102 200 200
```

The `rn` field is a proxy `PRIMARY KEY` - I presume your table has one? OK, so far so good. **But**, you can't put Window functions in a where clause, so this will be our basis for the following query:

```
SELECT 
  rn, d AS tx_date, a AS acct, la AS previous, price, le AS future,
  CASE
    WHEN le > la THEN 'Increase'
    ELSE 'Decrease'
  END AS action
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rn,
    t_date AS d, account AS a, 
    LAG(price) OVER () AS la, price, LEAD(price) OVER() AS le
  FROM share
) AS tab
WHERE le != la;
```

Result:

```
rn  tx_date     acct    previous    price   future  action
3   2020-02-01  102          200      200      210  Increase
5   2020-02-02  101          210      200      200  Decrease
```

So, this is, I think, pretty much what you wanted. Following tranaction 3, there was an increase and prior to transaction 5 there was a decrease. If you want the focus to be on transaction 4, then just play around with the SQL - it shouldn't be too difficult. Window/Analytic functions are **very** powerful and well worth learning! BTW, next time you ask a question, could you please provide your table structures as DDL (`CREATE TABLE foo...`) and your data as DML (`INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...`) - or use a fiddle. p.s. welcome to the forum!